# python mockito mocking of single method not working

Tags: python, mockito-python

In my class under test i have this call that i want to mock:

```
from models.crud import create_plane, get_plane_by_id

class PersistAircraftEvents:        
        ...
    def persist_aircraft_event(self, aircraft_event: ReceivedAircraftEvent):    
        ...
        # check if aircraft exists
        aircraft = get_plane_by_id(self._db, aircraft_id) # this i want to mock
```

in my test i have

```
from mockito import when
import models.crud

class TestPersistAircraftEvents:


    def test_unknown_aircraft_type(self):
        ...
        
        db: Session = mock()
        service = PersistAircraftEvents(db)
        event = ReceivedAircraftEvent(event_time=datetime.now(), aircraft_id="what?", event_type="test")
        when(models.crud).get_plane_by_id(...).thenReturn(None)

        service.persist_aircraft_event(event)
```

but the call is not mocked and the real function is called. I guess something is wrong with my import?

I also tried

```
import models
from model.crud import get_plane_by_id
```

even using `import models as something`

So how to mock arbitrary method calls correctly?